# add service reference failed after the service running

Tags: c#, wcf

I try to Host WCF in a Windows Service Using TCP using this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx

and after all the steps successfully pass include running the service i try to **Add a WCF Service Reference to the Client** so i created console application project and after try to add reference to my service i got this error:

```
The URI prefix is not recognized.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service1'.
Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service1. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:02.0072566. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8523. 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8523
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

This is my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service1" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

I also try `netstat -ap tcp` and cannot find my service connaction

Comment: How do you run the server, and on what OS?

Comment: Windows 8 x64, i run it from services.msc

Comment: Does the service start without any errors/exceptions? I'm asking, because I suspect a network listening permission problem. Consider for example this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/magazine/cc163531%28en-us%29.aspx

Comment: I didn't see any errors

Comment: Could you try this command: `netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:[your port number]/[your uri] user=[your domain]\[your user] listen=yes`? `[your domain]` and `[your user]` should match the user under which the service runs.